# Ansible: How to run one Task Host by Host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, task

On the play-level, we have `serial: 1` to allow us to run the whole play one host at a time. But I haven't found a simple way to do this on a single task. This is especially relevant, if the task in question doesn't perform proper locking (for whatever reason).

One obvious answer is to put the task in its own play. But that doesn't help with roles. (Having to put `serial: 1` on the play using the role isn't really intuitive.)

Comment: Similar Stackoverflow question: [Set forks for one task in ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33675888/427158)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can run a single task in serial (i.e. host-by-host) by adding `throttle: 1` to it.

Example:

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
      - name: wait in parallel
        command: sleep 20
      - name: wait  in serial
        command: sleep 30
        throttle: 1
```

References:

- [Using keywords to control execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#using-keywords-to-control-execution)
- [Playbook Keywords: Tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-131)

NB: `throttle` was introduced in Ansible 2.9

Comment: Yes, Ansible 2.9 was released end 2019, well after the question was asked.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want any parallelism in performing the steps in your playbook, set the fork level to 1:

```
ansible-playbook --forks=1 ...
```

You can also put this in your ansible cfg file:

```
[defaults]
forks=1
```

but if you want it on an individual basis, use the command line option above.

**EDIT:**

`serial: 1` does something completely different: that is like running the playbook for each host in turn, waiting for completion of the complete playbook before moving on to the next host. `forks=1` means run the first task in a play on one host before running the same task on the next host, so the first task will be run for each host before the next task is touched.

So you want `forks=1` for just one play; unfortunately that is not currently possible.

Comment: I was not looking to set this on a whole playbook. That's much to non-granular. `serial: 1` let's me set it on a play at least. But I only want to set it on a subitem of a play (what ever the correct name of that is. I thought, it was "task", but comment above seems to disagree).

Comment: `serial: 1` does something completely different: that is like running the playbook for each host in turn, waiting for completion of the complete playbook before moving on to the next host. `forks=1` means run the first task in a play on one host before running the *same* task on the next host, so the first task will be run for each host before the next task is touched. So you want `forks=1` for just one play; unfortunately that is not currently possible.

Comment: Good point! Would you mind adding that to the answer?

Answer (score 7):

There's a workaround to this problem - one can pass list of hosts (or a group) to `with_items`, and then use `delegate_to` with this list. This way task will be executed host by host.

For example:

```
- name: start and enable rabbitmq (run task host by host)
  service:
    name: "rabbitmq-server"
    state: "started"
    enabled: true
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups['rabbitmq-cluster'] }}"
  run_once: true
```

Comment: For those wondering why `run_once: true` is in there, try taking it out. You will not like what happens. (so many repeated runs aaaahhhh)

Answer (score 2):

If you are executing it on a single machine , then exclusive locks issue arises for more than one host .So you should execute one by one for all the hosts .For this you need to have `--forks=1` being set when calling ansible playbook command.
FOr example: `ansible-playbook webserver.yml --forks=1` where webserver.yml has **app01 and app02** inside your `[webserver]`

Answer (score 0):

For commands that can be run locally, use a loop to iterate over all the hosts in the play. This ONLY works if the command can be run locally. You could also run a command with ssh in it to the remote machines one by one in this manner, if keys are setup, but it becomes difficult when talking about escalation.

EG:

```
- name: Init New Appliances - Remove the known hosts entry for the server in case it has changed
  run_once: yes
  connection: local
  become: no
  command: "ssh-keygen -R {{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Comment: You have to provide a **list** of hosts instead of just on host named `inventory_hostname`, otherwise the loop makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I often have a set of etra tasks for some hosts in a play book, not all hosts, just some.

This was my solution...

```yaml
    - name: Include Host Tasks
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: >-
        {{ lookup("first_found",
           'host_tasks/'+inventory_hostname+'.yml', '/dev/null' ) }}
```

This will run the extra tasks for just that specific host, located in the 'host_tasks' sub-directory of the playbook, if present.  If there are no task file for that host nothing is done, and no error happens.   VERY useful!

Answer (score -2):

Think what you want is

run_once: true

Comment: nope: "run_once: true" means to run the task for exactly one host in the list of hosts. I want to run it for each host in the list, but one after the other.