# Serialization with Ansible with a jumpbox/build-server

Tags: automation, ansible, serial

We are using a build-server that is delegating_to and deploying the build to the application servers. I am not sure how we are going to "serialize" since everything is being done on the build-server ( 1 host ) and there are numerous application servers. The build-server is the only server able to talk to the application servers. This wouldn't be a problem, but we need to make sure to deploy to the app servers one by one(kicking/re-entering them into the pool when everything looks okay). Any suggestions?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/736452/126632

Comment: this won't work - we only have one build-server defined.. and numerous application servers

Answer (score 0):

The number of hosts an Ansible play is run in parallel can be defined with the `serial` parameter.

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial: 3
```

From the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html):

> By default, Ansible will try to manage all of the machines referenced in a play in parallel. For a rolling updates use case, you can define how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time by using the ‘’serial’’ keyword
>   In the above example, if we had 100 hosts, 3 hosts in the group ‘webservers’ would complete the play completely before moving on to the next 3 hosts.

If you want to deploy your app server one by one you need to define something like this in your play:

```
- name: Deploy app servers one by one
  hosts: appservers
  serial: 1
```